# How to set the Java version in JShell?

Tags: java, jshell

I'm using [JShell from JDK 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/jshell/introduction-jshell.html#GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8) to experiment some behaviors with generics.

I would like to set the interpreted java version to version 8. This would allow me to have the same type inference behaviors as defined in the [Java Language Specification 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

How can I do it?

Comment: I really doubt jshell is meant for something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The flag you would like to apply is:

```
"-source 8"
```

The way to pass this onto the compiler behind JShell would be:

```
"jshell -C "-source 11"
```

**... But it won't work.** I tried it just now, and the Jshell fails to parse this with an exception. It should not be the case, so I looked into the code of the Arguments class that throws the error. It turned out that `javac` options are grouped into different categories, and **only the `BASIC` commands are allowed via JShell** (com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option.java:1308).

Setting the source flag does not belong to this group, so the validator throws it out and the setting will not be applied.

*If you want to verify this, you can try to pass a BASIC type of param to the javac like "-p", and you will see it correctly passed.*

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible, JShell tool use Java Platform Module System (JPMS) that is a java 9 feature.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why JPMS is an obstacle to interpret expressions issued in JShell as Java 8 source code?